# IEEE 802.16e standard Codes

Tags: standards, ieee

I'm working on an article about traping sets in LDPC codes. In numerical result part, writers check their algorithm on Codes C1 and C2 which are the LDPC codes with girth 6 and block lengths 576 and 1056, respectively, used in the IEEE 802.16e standard, but I can't find the matrix of these two parity check codes. Can anyone help me?

Comment: anyone? please..

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the standard here: https://standards.ieee.org/standard/802_16e-2005.html

It must contain all the information necessary (if it is actually part of the IEEE 802.16e standard).